# Как сделать "резиновый" div?

Tags: php, html

.nav - панель, где располагаются два div'a

.divnal - те самые два блока

```
.devnav{
margin-left: 250px;
width: 20%; 
display: inline-block;
text-align: center; 
color: #ffffff;
margin-top: 15px; 
font-size: 18px;}

.nav{
height: 99px;
background: #3351eb;}
```

На родном мониторе (1280х1024) работает идеально - https://i.stack.imgur.com/la3nB.png

но если проверяю, например, на самом большом мониторе, то совсем не соответствует тому, что у меня.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nd0as.png

Изменил код

```
.devnav{
width: 50%; 
float: left;
text-align: center; 
color: #ffffff;
margin-top: 15px; 
font-size: 18px;}
```

Только опять проблема в том, что на больших экранах они отдаляются друг от друга
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZ87i.png

Answer (score 2):

Сделай например так

HTML:

```
<div class="nav">
<div class="inner-wrap">
<div class="devnav"></div>
<div class="devnav"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav {
width:100%;
height:99px;
}

    .inner-wrap {
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto
    }

    .devnav{
    width: 50%; 
    float: left;
    text-align: center; 
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 15px; 
    font-size: 18px;}
```

Comment: То что надо. Спасибо!

Comment: закройте вопрос )

Comment: @user207012, если ответ помог, отметьте его решением.

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Comment: что именно сделать ?

Comment: @user207012, галочку поставьте на ответе)

Answer (score 1):

Ширину сделать на половину

```
width:50%;
```

А margin убрать.

Comment: в .nav или .devnav?

Comment: сделал. Теперь у меня все вертикально встало

Comment: я понял мысль, теперь только нужно поставить их горизонтально. Только не понимаю, почему не работает эта строка: display: inline-block;

Comment: попробую применить float